# Problems with IIS 7.5 frequently going down for no good reason

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7.5

We have a dedicated system (Windows Server 2008) with Hostway that just got deployed and we seem to be having a problem.
Since we started using this server, during the night, our monitoring software (IP Check) goes crazy for one of the 8 sites listed. The HTTP and DB service for this site seem to drop all the time.
We have three sites that use Classic ASP and I've set their application pools to recycle themselves, but I can't think of anything else.
I'm not seeing anything in the event logs that look like they would cause the IIS server to fail and go down, and I'm not a server guy, so I'm wondering where should I start to try and troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need a bit more information.  Things to check.  Is this site a asp.net or classic asp?  Classic asp is harder to troubleshoot.

1) Is the application recording any errors?

2) What does the cpu and memory look like during this time?

3) Do you have any long running pages?  Log parser can help with this
http://www.iislogs.com/steveschofield/webfarm-performance-tips

4) I'd start collecting some perfmon if you have access to the server.  If not, have you engaged your hosting provider? Let the perf counters run, start with basics web service, cpu, memory, logical / physical disk.

5) I would put or verify the troublesome site in it's own application pool. 
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753449(v=ws.10).aspx

6) is a bot hitting your site?  The iis logs will provide some options there.

7) Are we talking hundreds or thousands of users on the server?  Key counters to look for is requests / per sec, concurrent connections,

good article
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2008.08.pulse.aspx